# Is it possible to configure a unity project so it only runs on a device?

Tags: unity, android

I am want to give someone a sample Android Unity project and I want them to be able to run it only on a device, not the simulator. Is there a way that I can configure the project so that it will only run on a device?

Comment: It might work if you required a touch screen from the Android manifest file...

Comment: This seems unlikely. The point of a simulator is to pretend it's a device.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto The simulator simulates those resources.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @jhocking Most of the time when I send samples for people to test out on devices, they try to play it in the simulator and always give feedback that it's not working well, though I also emphasize that it should be played on a device. A you know, first impressions last. If it cannot be run on a simulator it will compel them to just run it on the device.

Comment: @Containment Will it? Won't they just complain that it's "not working" and leave you there? If they're not bothering to listen to your advice that it should be run on a device will they bother reading the part of your instructions that say "can't be run on a simulator"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very well-versed with Unity and Android interaction but perhaps you can use [android developer's answer over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21505193/5615635) to identify if you're running on an Android emulator and then terminate the application if `isEmulator` returns true.

Here's what you need to check to see if the app is an emulator. If any of these statements (one for each line) return true it is an emulator.

```
Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic");
Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown");
Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk");
Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator");
Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86");
Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion");
(Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic")); // Note the &&
"google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
```

Comment: Wouldn't fingerprint be unknown if, say, the device *did not have a fingerprint scanner*?

Comment: @Gnemlock Not sure but the documentation doesn't mention anything about it and lots of other people seem to be using this method so I feel like it should work anyways. I'd have to do more research when I have access to a better device.

Comment: On closer inspection, there *may* be another issue. The quoted answer appears to deal with *android app development*, where "emulator" would refer to the android emulator available with the android sdk. This user appears to be referring to emulator as, atleast in part, *playing the game from the Unity application*. If that is the case, this answer may not be *as* applicable (again, easy enough to test); the android emulator with the sdk is notoriously horrible. I can almost guarantee it is not being used in Unity, so there may be alternate behaviours.

Comment: Id say try this out from a UI button (draw a button to the inspector that debug outputs all of these checks as individual logs). If your not sure how, look up "custom inspector" in the unity manual. They provide enough placeholder detail for generic inspector buttons. Good luck!